# Node routes works fine on local but not in heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

I'm trying to deploy an app into Heroku but it doesn't work.

When in local it renders the JSON on the screen but in Heroku, it keeps loading and after a while throws a Request timeout error. What could be causing this?

```js
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("home");
});

app.get("/info", (req, res) => {
  Person.find({}).then((result) => {
    res.send(
      `<div>
          <p>Phonebook has info for ${result.length} people</p>
          <p>Get request was made at ${new Date()}</p>
      </div>`
    );
  });
});

app.get("/api/persons", (req, res) => {
  Person.find({}).then((result) => {
    res.json(result);
  });
});
```

These are my get request, I have more but the only one that works is "/".

```js
const personSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 5,
    required: true,
  },
  number: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 3,
    required: true,
  },
});

personSchema.set("toJSON", {
  transform: (document, returnedObject) => {
    returnedObject.id = returnedObject._id;
    delete returnedObject._id;
    delete returnedObject.__v;
  },
});

const Person = model("Person", personSchema);
```

Comment: If you have the Heroku CLI installed you can run `heroku logs --tail --app you_app_name` and see what is being logged. I would put a console.log at the beginning of each route to see if you are getting into the route at all and check for errors.

Comment: Yes I did that, in the logs the only error that shows up is after i get the request timeout on the page: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/persons" status=503. And for the console.log, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: How are you setting up your port? Something like const port = process.env.port || 3000 ? Also can you add any warning on errors you get when you deploy. Or atleast any of the relevant success messages on the deployment?

Comment: const port = process.env.port i'm doing it like that without the || 3000. I could not fix it yet, I tried to deploy in vercel instead of heroku and it does not throw me errors, it shows me on the screen everything I have in my index.js and it does not matter if I change the path in the url, it keeps showing me the code in the browser